# How to trigger branch scans in a declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline that changes some files in 5 repositories containing Jenkinsfiles. The pipeline then puts a tag on the corresponding commits. In the same pipeline i build these Multibranch-Pipelines via said tags. Unfortunately i have to wait until the automatic branch scans triggered (I set it to 1 minute, which is "spamming" my controllers executors). I want to be able to trigger the scans right after i push my changes but i have yet to find a solution to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try and set a [Downstream pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html) relationship between:

- the pipeline which pushed the tag
- the multi-branch pipeline which should be activated when the tag is pushed.

> A downstream pipeline is any GitLab CI/CD pipeline triggered by another pipeline. A downstream pipeline can be either:
>
> - A parent-child pipeline, which is a downstream pipeline triggered in the same project as the first pipeline.
> - A multi-project pipeline, which is a downstream pipeline triggered in a different project than the first pipeline.

That way, the first pipeline can call directly the second one.

Comment: I have it configured that way, that the first pipeline calls the second one with the specific tag, but it throws errors when trying to build said tag because without the scan, Jenkins does not recognize it. Maybe i'm understanding it wrong on how to do it. We are not running GitLabs if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Julian Than may be the first pipeline should create and push the tag, before calling the second pipeline which would fetch tags, then proceed with the rest of its script.